# Screen displaying error on mobile device, is fine on emulator

Tags: flutter, dart, listview

[image: mobile phone]

[image: emulator]

I get this huge grey text (which i think is an error message) on my mobile phone, wheras on the emulator the content loads fine. The body is just a listview with some data from firebase.

Body code:

```
body: Center(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Expanded(
              child: FutureBuilder(
                future: getDocID(),
                builder: (context, snapshot) {
                  return ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: docIDs.length,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                      return Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                            vertical: 10, horizontal: 8),
                        child: ListTile(
                          dense: true,
                          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8)),
                          
                          title: Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                horizontal: 10, vertical: 4),
                            child: Column(
                              children: [
                                SizedBox(
                                  height: 5,
                                ),
                                Align(
                                  alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                                  child: Title(
                                    color: Colors.black,
                                    child: GetActivities(
                                        documentID: docIDs[index]),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      );
                    },
                  );
                },
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
```

GetActivity code:

```
class GetActivities extends StatelessWidget {
  final String documentID;
  GetActivities({required this.documentID});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    CollectionReference users =
        FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('activities');

    return FutureBuilder<DocumentSnapshot>(
      future: users.doc(documentID).get(),
      builder: ((context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
          Map<String, dynamic> data =
              snapshot.data!.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
          return Text(
            '${data['title']}',
          );
        }
        return Text('loading...');
      }),
    );
  }
}
```

Would appreciate any help to tell me why this problem occurs, and how to solve it. thanks

Comment: Try Removing the expanded widget inside the column.

Comment: Didn't fix the issue

Comment: Actually removing it did work, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Remove expanded widget inside the column.

Answer (score 0):

go to manifest in this paht
*android/app/src/**main**/androidManifest*
and check if you use internet permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

your error maybe because you used debug mode in emulator, so internet permission declaration by default but not in *android/app/src/**main**/androidManifest*
and release mode in real device